# Angular 5 Route Guard with Observables

Tags: angular

I am trying to lock a XYZ component, when one user login to the app and if another user tries to login cannot view the XYZ component.

I have stored the current user in local storage when user logs in.
Also the current user in DB/API

If an user login and go to the XYZ component,the current username will be updated in api, if there is no user logged in the value will be null.

There is a LockGuard which will check if the current user and DB user are same. But i am having issues with the data that is returned from API.

Here is my code:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(this.service.isLocked()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        return false;
    }
}


public isLocked() {
  let user = this.getCurrentUser();
  this.checkCurrentUser().subscribe(item => {
      // not getting value here: Observable not working here.
      this.existingLockedUser = item.currentUser;

      return user.username == this.existingLockedUser ? true : false;
  });
}


public checkCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
  let id = 1;
  let url = CONFIG.urls.lockedUser + '/' + id;
  return this.http.get(url)
      .map((res:any) => {
          return res;
      })
}


public getCurrentUser() {
  this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  return this.currentUser;
}
```

Comment: `return this.checkCurrentUser().subscribe(item => {` just add a return here.

Comment: What is the value of `item`?

Comment: username of user.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 5 you can do simply like this:

```
public checkCurrentUser() {
  let id = 1;
  let url = CONFIG.urls.lockedUser + '/' + id;
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `isLocked` does not return anything.
You can return the Observable from checkCurrentUser and map it to the needed boolean:

```
public isLocked() {
    let user = this.getCurrentUser();
    return this.checkCurrentUser().pipe(
        map(item => item.currentUser),
        map(currentUser => user.username == currentUser));
}
```

And return the Observable in your `canActivate` function and additionally check the value of isLocked to redirect to your login-page:

```
public canActive() {
    return this.isLocked()
        .do(locked => {
            if(!locked) {
                this.router.navigate(['/login'])
            }
        })
   }
```

Additional imports needed:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the canActivate return type to **boolean**

```
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {
        constructor(private router: Router) {
        }

        canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,  state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
            if(!this.checkLogin()){
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
                   return this.checkLogin();
        }

        checkLogin(): boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
```

If you want you could use observables and do not change your type, but you should return it in  **checkLogin** method

```
 @Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

        var obs = this.checkLogin();    
        return obs.do(x => {
            if (!x) {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        });
    }

    canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> {           
        return this.checkLogin();
    }

    checkLogin(): Observable<boolean> {
        return Observable.of(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `do` in obs.do?

Comment: It's a side effect. 'Do' some action and not interfere with the result.

Comment: you meant `tap`

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html 
'If you are using as a pipeable operator, do is known as tap!' 
It seems I did meant 'tap'